# Nginx Config for IP Address URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, puma

I wish to setup my URL like this `https://IP_ADDRESS/`. I have already setup rails and puma and I'm struggling with the Nginx config. My server is on Ubuntu 16.04.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default :

```
upstream app-name-production-backend {
  server unix:///home/rails/apps/app-name/production/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /home/rails/apps/app-name/production/current/public/;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_redirect off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app-name-production-backend;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Is my Nginx config correct?

Comment: Does it work with `http://IP_ADDRESS` ? In your nginx config change `server_name _;` to `server_name IP_ADDRESS;`

Comment: It doesn't work with http and it doesn't work with the ip_address as the server name

Comment: What does the page display ?

Comment: "This site can’t be reached
IP_ADDRESS refused to connect."

Comment: Could you try the conf in the answer. Take a look at digitalocean tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#install-and-configure-nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue I was having is that I had the `force_ssl` statement in the `application_controller.rb`, this was forcing everything through `https` (port 443) and not serving anything through `http` (port 80) and because port 443 was not configured and I didn't have any SSL certificates in place it was displaying the `This site can’t be reached` (on chrome) message.

Comment: Ok ! I'm deleting my useless answer